# CNContactStore retrieve a contact by email address

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I would like to use the Contacts Framework (IOS 9) to retrieve contacts that matching an email address.

Any help will be appreciated.
Objective C please.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do this too. Did you figure out a way?

Comment: Maybe this page can help you: https://gist.github.com/willthink/024f1394474e70904728

Answer (score 8):

1. Add Contacts.framework
2. `#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>`
3. write code

```
-(void)loadContactList {
    CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];
    if( status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
    {
        NSLog(@"access denied");
    }
    else
    {
        //Create repository objects contacts
        CNContactStore *contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
        //Select the contact you want to import the key attribute  ( https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Metadata_Keys )

        NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys, nil];

        // Create a request object
        CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keys];
        request.predicate = nil;

        [contactStore enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request
                                                  error:nil
                                             usingBlock:^(CNContact* __nonnull contact, BOOL* __nonnull stop)
         {
             // Contact one each function block is executed whenever you get
             NSString *phoneNumber = @"";
             if( contact.phoneNumbers)
                 phoneNumber = [[[contact.phoneNumbers firstObject] value] stringValue];

             NSLog(@"phoneNumber = %@", phoneNumber);
             NSLog(@"givenName = %@", contact.givenName);
             NSLog(@"familyName = %@", contact.familyName);
             NSLog(@"email = %@", contact.emailAddresses);


             [contactList addObject:contact];
         }];

        [contactTableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I search for a single contact called "Johnny Appleseed" ?

Comment: How to I retrieve all contacts whose first name is "John"?

Comment: @josh  you would want to replace   

request.predicate = nil;

with

request.predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsMatchingName:@"Johnny Appleseed"];

Comment: Thanks, that was quite helpful! @J3RM

Comment: works like a charm thank you!! .... just a point of reference for junior devs. for "1. add Contacts.framework".... you must go into .xcodeproj -> general -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Contents ... and then add item 'Contacts.framework' (and as well maybe 'ContactsUI.framework' if desired)... also the variables listed in this example 'contactList' & 'contactTableView' are class scope variables and not part of the framework, hence you will likely get errors if you simply try to copy and paste. thanks again @minjoongkim, great example!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I stumbled on it looking to do this too. Sharing how to do this on iOS11 and above.

```
NSString* emailAddress = @"John-Appleseed@mac.com";
//Create repository objects contacts
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

NSPredicate* predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsMatchingEmailAddress:emailAddress];
NSArray* keysToFetch = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
NSError *error;
NSArray *contacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keysToFetch error:&error];
if (error) {
       NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
} else {
   for (CNContact *contact in contacts) {
       NSLog(@"%@", contact.givenName);
   }
}
```