# iOS: CNContact fetching contacts using email

Tags: swift2, cncontact

I have added emails to my contacts but I do not understand how I can find contacts by email. If I use Contacts app on my iPad I can type an email in the search field and it will find the contact it belongs to. What search method should I implement to enable this in my app? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Refer to this answer. It worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34651556/1631695

Comment: The answer you link to explains how to fetch contacts by name, but not how to fetch by email address. 

To do that I think you will need to fetch all, then select by email address.