# How to differentiate the phone numbers after fetching the details from local contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cncontact

I am fetching the mobile contacts by using below method

```
-(void)fetchContactsandAuthorization
{
    // Request authorization to Contacts
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES)
        {
            //make sure that you have added the necessary properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPostalAddressesKey];
            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];

            NSLog(@"new %@",cnContacts);

            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *phone;
                NSString *fullName;
                NSString *firstName;
                NSString *lastName;
                NSString *companyName;
                NSString *departmentName;
                NSString *jobTitleName;
                NSString *address;
                NSString *iden;
                NSString *emailAddress;

                UIImage *profileImage;

                NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                NSMutableArray *addressArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                NSMutableArray *emailAddressArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                    // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                    firstName = contact.givenName;
                    lastName = contact.familyName;
                    iden = contact.identifier;


                    if (lastName == nil) {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                    }else if (firstName == nil){
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                    }
                    else{
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                    }
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];

                    NSLog(@"imgold %@",image);
                    if (image != nil) {
                        profileImage = image;
                    }else{
                        profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
                    }
                    for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                        phone = [label.value stringValue];
                        if ([phone length] > 0) {
                            [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                        }
                    }
                    NSLog(@"PhonenumberArray %@",contactNumbersArray);


                    User *user = [User new];
                    user.fullName=fullName;
                    user.image= profileImage;
                    user.phone= phone;
                    user.idUser= iden;
                    [contacts addObject:user];

                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [_selectContactListTblView reloadData];
                });
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I am able to get all phone numbers associated with the contact and able to store in an array.

```
PhonenumberArray (
    "98708\U00a001224",
    "98920\U00a077702",
    "93240\U00a077702",
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9
)
```

Now i want to differentiate the phonenumbers in array like home,mobile,fax,pager etc. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34651556/6656894 refer this ans

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya, check your link. It shows how to get phonenumber which i am already able to do. My question is to identify the phonenumber label like home or mobile etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `CNLabeledValue` label property will return a string that represents home, mobile etc.  Then call `[CNLabeledValue localizedStringForLabel:labelString]` to get a localized human readable string.

```
for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
    phone = [label.value stringValue];
    labelString = label.label;
    if ([phone length] > 0) {
         [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
         [contactNumbersLabelsArray addObject:labelString];
    }
```

}

Comment: if possible can you post some sample code to call [CNLabeledValue localizedStringForLabel:labelString]

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog https://genericswift.wordpress.com/, It will fetch all contacts from contact store and will differentiate it with home,mobile,fax,pager etc.

Code is in this Github link https://github.com/VinupriyaArivazhagan/AVContactPickerController

Just need a line of code to pesent view controller with all fetched contacts

```
AVContactPickerController.present(title: "Contact", maximumContactCount: nil, updateDesign: nil)
```

and can update design as well

```
AVContactPickerController.present(title: "Contact", maximumContactCount: 2, updateDesign: { controller in

            controller.checkImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Clicked")
            controller.uncheckImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Click")
            controller.closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        })
```

Comment: This is swift. My code is objective c. Please post any reference related to objective c.

Comment: @Madhu,  You can call swift class function from objective c, add that swift file in your project folder, do necessary steps( just google to get extra info), then you can call swift class file function from objective c class file

Comment: See that blog to how to use that swift file

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to build it in objective c. I cannot use swift file in my project.